how to convert non-indexed variables to indexed-variables in MATLAB?
I am working with some mathematical expression in MATLAB with six variables where W = f(X1,....., X6).
I need to convert all the non indexed variables to index variables such that W(i,j,k,l,m,n)= f[X1(i),X2(j), X3(k),X4(l),X5(m),X6(n)]. I need to do it using adequate code rather than do it manually.
I tried *sub order but didn't work properly

did you try ind2sub command?

I figure it out :
tic 
 for i=1:size (X1)
 x1=X1(i);
 for j=1:size (X2)
 x2=X2(j);
 for k=1:size (X3)
 x3=X3(k);
 for l=1:size (X4)
 x4=X4(l);
 for m=1:size (X5)
 x5=X5(m);
 for n=1:size (X6)
 x6=X6(n);
 W(i,j,k,l,m,n)=........
 end
 end
 end
 end
 end
 end
toc
                      

